# Python For Loop, run calculation, and append final results

Tags: python

I have a list of Line of Business (for example: Amazon, Ralphs, Target, etc) that I want to run the stats analysis and append final result.

But, my query can do analysis 1 line of business at a time. How can I do run script multiple times based on the list of line of business and append the final result from every combination to a list?

```
>>> LOB1 = input("Line of Business: ")

>>> spec_sku = spec_sku.loc[spec_sku['LOB'] == LOB1]
>>> spec_sku.head()

           Date      LOB       PG       Sales
60639   7 Sep 19    Amazon  Snacks 5pk  8370.0
60640   14 Sep 19   Amazon  Snacks 5pk  12360.0
60641   21 Sep 19   Amazon  Snacks 5pk  8280.0
60642   28 Sep 19   Amazon  Snacks 5pk  6450.0
60643   5 Oct 19    Amazon  Snacks 5pk  7620.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the query function to filter on multiple businesses at once.

```
spec_sku.query("LOB in ['Amazon', 'Ralphs', 'Target']")
```